# Why does "cat /proc/net/dev" show only 0 for non-root users?

Tags: networking, debian, unix

Recently, I've noticed that my script to monitor the network showed me nothing at all when it was run with a non root user.

My script is simply looking at `/proc/net/dev` which has the following permission (444):

```
-r--r--r--  1 root  root 0 Feb 26 09:31 dev
```

However, even if everyone has read access, I noticed that non-root users cannot obtain any data

```
> cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
dummy0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
 bond0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
ip6tnl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
 tunl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

When I add sudo to the command here is the result I get

```
> sudo cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0: 69684609  360869    0    0    0     0          0    234060 419896366  484740    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
dummy0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
 bond0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
ip6tnl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 113595057  801133    0    0    0     0          0         0 113595057  801133    0    0    0     0       0          0
 tunl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

I'm interested in knowing why does /proc/net/dev has this behaviour ?

By the way, my server is using Debian 8.3 (Jessie).

Comment: Hello, I just installed a new debian 8.3 to test this. I get the same result from a user and root user and it's not all zeroes. For your info my /proc/net/dev has the same permissions and ownership. My user was created by Debian installer and looks like that `uid=1000(test) gid=1000(test) groups=1000(test),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev)` so you can compare. I tried with another user I created myself, it also works.
How did you create your user ?

Comment: @pat Here are the information about my user `uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),8(mail)`. It was created by the root user using `adduser` command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955724/regular-user-cant-read-proc-net-dev
have you checked this link before ?

Comment: @pat Nope, I didn't checked this link before, but it's the right answer. Post it and I'll accept it =) Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955724/regular-user-cant-read-proc-net-dev

Your kernel is probably using the grsec compilation option which prevents you from accessing the stats. You should try with another kernel.

Comment: "You may award your bounty in 21 hours." I'll not forget !